# How to Change Root View from anywhere in appliction in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, rootview

I have developed an app without storyboard.

I have a functionality of Logout. When user click on logout then I have to redirect him to the sign in page and clear all navigation stack and make sign in page root view.

I am trying with this code but using this my app crashes:

```
 SignUpVC *main = [[SignUpVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignUpVC" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:main];

[self presentViewController:main animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: what is the message error? (I have did this before, in my case I did a 
popToRootViewControllerAnimated in the current NavigationController)

Comment: If if i use `popToRooTViewController` then it take me to current root. my new root is not working

Comment: use setViewControllers, it Replaces the view controllers currently managed by the navigation controller with the specified items.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:

Comment: so what you are asking is to set view controller for your navigation controller ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri No...I want to take user back to first screen..and make that screen root view

Comment: can u explain about your error after this code ? 
you can do it very easy !
please explain more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the root view of the application you can do it in this way

```
SignUpVC *main = [[SignUpVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignUpVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:main];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:navController];
```